# R: Primitive Function - For Historical or Efficiency Reasons?

Tags: r

How would I find list of primitive functions in R meant for historical or efficiency reasons?

Primitive functions are the ones that provide links between R code and the C code used to write R.

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by "Primitive Function."  Do you mean a function included in the base R install, or what R calls a Primitive--functions called by an R wrapper which merely calls the internal C primitive.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for the handy chunk of code. How would I separate the list of functions for historical or efficiency purpose? Perhaps, I need to scan through the documents of all these functions.

Comment: @Josh: aside from the main question, names(methods:::.BasicFunsList)  shows 191 functions, but you got one extra function in it.

Comment: I'm using R-devel, and the list is subject to change. Apparently it's gotten longer since the version that you're using ;)

Comment: Efficiency is the motivation for most/all `.Primitive()` calls. (It's even more efficient than calling `.Internal()`.) [This section of the R internals manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive) lays out very nicely the different types of primitive functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will get you the names of all R functions that wrap calls to `.Primitive()`:

```
nms <- names(methods:::.BasicFunsList)        ## ?.BasicFunsList for more info

length(nms)
# [1] 192
c(head(nms, 8), tail(nms, 8))
#  [1] "$"          "$<-"        "["          "[<-"       
#  [5] "[["         "[[<-"       "%*%"        "xtfrm"     
#  [9] "switch"     "tracemem"   "unclass"    "untracemem"
# [13] "while"      "{"          "||"         "~"
```

Answer (score -3):

[This](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) is the the manual by Cran, which has a lot of information regarding historical and efficiency. It has a brief introduction of R commands and which one is better to use in which scenario.