# Not able to find body of class

Tags: r

I am able to find the body of lapply. But I am not able to find the same for class. `body(class)`. I get NULL.

```
body(lapply)
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
        X <- as.list(X)
    .Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you type:

```
class
```

the output is:

```
function (x)  .Primitive("class")
```

you see that `class` is a primitive function. So it is written in `C` and don't have an `R` body.

To get the list of all primitive functions, one can do:

```
names(methods:::.BasicFunsList)
```

And for the list of all function included by default with R you can see the [List of R default packages](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/packages.html)

Comment: ALso can I see what all are written in R and C?

Comment: @imranp I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was, Can I see what all functions are written in R and C? Like we have class written in C and likewise :)

Comment: So basically the list of functions written in C or the list of functions written in R?

Comment: For the `primitives` you can do `names(methods:::.BasicFunsList)`  [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632246/r-primitive-function-for-historical-or-efficiency-reasons)